# eBay to Salesforce CRM Connector

Tags: connected-apps, crm

The company I work for has an eBay store with a hundred weekly orders. Customer service is a pain, as almost all other CS enquiries are handled within Salesforce and only eBay requires us to manage customer enquiries via their interface. And we lose track on those issues and don't know what enquiries we get or how long they take to resolve.

We'd like eBay messages to automatically create a Salesforce case and replies to the case go straight to the eBay message from said customer.
And we'd like to know about escalations - when a buyer raises a case with eBay - and respond to those within Salesforce.

Is there an off-the-shelf software solution that can take care of this? Has anyone got experience with this?

Thanks!